# How to hide aliases from help screen in a cobra app

Tags: go, go-cobra

Is it possible to suppress `Aliases` to show up in the help screen of a golang `cobra` app? I basically would like to get rid of the whole "Aliases" section below:

```
Usage:
  my-app [flags]

Aliases:
 alias1 , alias2

Flags:
  -h, --help              help for this command
```

I know it's possible to hide flags from showing up in help (`cmd.Flags().MarkHidden("myflag")`). Is it somehow possible to hide Aliases as well?

Answer (score 3):

That would mean defining your own Usage function, which is possible using [`usageFunc`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/5155946348eed0f79a76f7743407c0c933e3b5f0/command.go#L188-L189)
Or using a specific Usage template ([`command#SetUsageTemplate()`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/5155946348eed0f79a76f7743407c0c933e3b5f0/command.go#L256-L259)), as stated in the ["Defining your own usage" `README` section](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/e392f3204db0445f1f4ad47448b04d8c8ad04c2a/README.md#defining-your-own-usage).

You can see the [default template here](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/5155946348eed0f79a76f7743407c0c933e3b5f0/command.go#L468-L501). It does include an Aliases section:

```
Aliases:
  {{.NameAndAliases}}{{end}}{{if .HasExample}}
```

All you would need is define the same temaplate, but exclusing the `Aliases` part.

You can see an example of [such a temmplate for `emacski/redact`](https://github.com/emacski/redact/blob/2b1380f943e9e963758bfc3d6f6f71ac5ab01373/redact/cmd.go#L15-L27).
And yes, it has no `Aliases`.

```
{{with (or .Long .Short)}}{{. | trimTrailingWhitespaces}}{{end}}
{{if .HasAvailableLocalFlags}}
Options:
{{.LocalFlags.FlagUsages | trimTrailingWhitespaces}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableSubCommands}}
Commands:{{range .Commands}}{{if (or .IsAvailableCommand (eq .Name "help"))}}
  {{rpad .Name .NamePadding }} {{.Short}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableSubCommands}}
Use "{{.CommandPath}} COMMAND --help" for more information about a command.{{end}}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

use custom Usage template, just remove alias part

```
customUsageTpl:=`Usage:{{if .Runnable}}
  {{.UseLine}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableSubCommands}}
  {{.CommandPath}} [command]{{end}}{{if .HasExample}}
Examples:
{{.Example}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableSubCommands}}
Available Commands:{{range .Commands}}{{if (or .IsAvailableCommand (eq .Name "help"))}}
  {{rpad .Name .NamePadding }} {{.Short}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableLocalFlags}}
Flags:
{{.LocalFlags.FlagUsages | trimTrailingWhitespaces}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableInheritedFlags}}
Global Flags:
{{.InheritedFlags.FlagUsages | trimTrailingWhitespaces}}{{end}}{{if .HasHelpSubCommands}}
Additional help topics:{{range .Commands}}{{if .IsAdditionalHelpTopicCommand}}
  {{rpad .CommandPath .CommandPathPadding}} {{.Short}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if .HasAvailableSubCommands}}
Use "{{.CommandPath}} [command] --help" for more information about a command.{{end}}
`
```

Then set custom template

```
cmd.SetUsageTemplate(customUsageTpl)
```

Comment: Yes, I did mention `setUsageTemplate` in my answer. And I did reference the default usage template with https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/5155946348eed0f79a76f7743407c0c933e3b5f0/command.go#L468-L501 in my answer.